# C++: How to write to a file directly (no ASCII)?

Tags: c++, file

I need to write to a file directly (file format/extension doesn't matter). What I want to be able to do is, e.g. write A to it, and if I opened the file with a hex editor, it would display A, a.k.a. the value 10 in decimal.

Comment: use fstream and open with ios::binary

Comment: I don't think that will work, as you need to write to it using write() and that only accepts char arrays which interpret 'A' as the character, and not as simply a value to write to it.

Comment: A `char` only interprets `'A'` as a character because you assign `'A'` to it. Assign `0xA` or `10` to a `char` instead and you have what you want. This is nothing to do with files, the question is "how do I assign the value `0xA` to a `char`?" and phrased like that it should be obvious. Just do it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    std::ofstream fout("myfile.ext", std::ios::binary);
    std::ofstream::char_type byte = 10; //or = 0xA
    fout.put(byte);
}
```

Comment: To be frank, for this sort of thing, I'd probably use system level IO, but this will work.

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you write `'A'` to the file, I'd expect the hex editor to show 41.

But let's say we have an `int x = 0xa;`, then the way to write that to a file is:

```
int x = 0xa;
ofstream out("myfile.txt", ios::out|ios::binary);

out.write((char *)&x, sizeof(x)); 

out.close();
```

Note that this code isn't highly portable, since size of `int` and the order of bytes within an integer can change from architecture to architecture.

Comment: That's awfully system dependent.  Depending on the system, you'll write different numbers of bytes (2, 4 or 6 on systems I'm aware of), with the actual `0x0A` in different bytes depending on the system.

Comment: Yes, of course, it won't write a single byte. I thought it more useful to show how to use `write`, as someone who wants to write more than one byte may benefit from that. But I guess that wasn't exactly what the question was...

Comment: Except that what you show is precisely how _not_ to write more than one byte.  If your data types are more than one byte, you have to format them into a buffer (`char[]`).  The fact that you need a `reinterpret_cast` to call the function should be a tip-off that you're doing something wrong.

Comment: Only if you actually need the data to be portable. Is it some rule on SO that everything has to be standards compliant, work on odd hardware that no one has actually ever seen?

Comment: No, but in this case, "portable" means being able to be read by code compiled with the next version of the compiler.  In other words, it's rare not to need this degree of portability.

Comment: Assuming "next version of the compiler" doesn't also mean "for a completely different processor architecture", I don't see how that would change the size of integer. Only time I've had compilers (targetting the "same" OS) change size of `int` was when I moved from OS/2 1.x (16-bit) to OS/2 3.x which was 32-bits. Other than that, I've only ever used strictly 16 or strictly 32-bit integer C++ or C compilers on the platforms that I've been using - which is 8086, 80186, x86_32, x86_64, 29K, 68K, ARM, PDP-11, VAX, Mips. I've also worked with a few processors where I never used a C/C++ compilers...

Comment: I have however added a paragraph saying it's not very portable.

Comment: I've seen compilers change the byte order of a long from one version to the next.  Change in floating point format was frequent in the past.  And of course, people do upgrade their machines---I'm in the process of converting a very large application from 32bits to 64.  (If it had been written correctly to begin with, of course, all that would be needed would be to recompile it.)